# Include momentjs in own definition files in typescript

Tags: typescript

I write my own *.d.ts definition files for my project. Some type definitions relay on the javascript library moment.

In the (normal) *.ts files i can import moment with `import * as moment from 'moment'` and refer to the moment object as `moment.Moment` but i didn't get it work in the definition files.

i tried 
`/// <reference path="<path-to-modules>/node_modules/moment/moment.d.ts" />` (with no effect)

`import * as moment from 'moment'` (with the effect that the following declarations can't be used anymore)

So, what is the right way to import the moment namespace to my own definition files?

Answer (score 0):

> what is the right way to import the moment namespace to my own definition files

The right way is what you mentioned :

```
import * as moment from 'moment'
```

> (with the effect that the following declarations can't be used anymore

They can be used. Your library depends on moment and `npm install` should install moment for your users. Alternatively have `moment` as a `peerDependency` and mention users that they should install `moment` (if they don't they will get TypeScript errors anyways )